# SAP HANA Find the days between two dates that are in different rows partition by an id

Tags: sql, hana

I have a table

ID Date
1  29/11/23
1  16/10/23
2  28/1/23
2  20/1/23

I am trying to find the difference between 29/11/23 and 16/10/23 for ID 1 and 20/1/23 and 28/1/23 for ID 2.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

To find the number of days between two dates in different rows partitioned by an ID in SAP HANA, you can use the SQL DATEDIFF function. Here's a query that does that:

```
SELECT id, DATEDIFF(DAY, MIN(Date), MAX(Date)) AS days_between
FROM your_table_name
GROUP BY id;
```

This query will give you the difference in days between the minimum and maximum dates for each ID in your table. In your example, it will produce the following result:

| id | days_between |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 44 |
| 2 | 8 |

Comment: Since you're already determining `MIN` and `MAX`, you do not disregard the order (the smaller date is always first) and cannot obtain negative values.

Comment: Yes, you're right. Getting negative values between two dates directly can be difficult with the DATEDIFF function. I think additional logic or calculations will be needed to solve this problem.